# Get children of instances in the same query on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

It's needed to retrieve all children of all objects in one active record query, but these don't work:

`Class.includes(:children)`

`Class.joins(:children).uniq.all`

Neither of two retrieve the children. It's needed a response like:

object : `{ "param1":"value1", ... "children" : [...] }`

It's something like .with() in Eloquent ORM (PHP)

Comment: Can you start from the children? Do you know the IDs of the parent class? i.e.: `Children.where(parent_id: Parent.ids)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to include the children formatted as JSON. This would return what you want:

```
Foo.find(1).as_json({ include: :bars })
# => {"foo"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"first", :bars=>[{"id"=>1, "amount"=>5}, {"id"=>2, "amount"=>5}]}}
```

You can look at the API documentation for [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) to see what other options you can use. Some common ones are `methods` and `only` to limit the fields returned.